# How exactly does this C program read in data from this binary file?

Tags: c, io, binary, low-level

My professor showed us an example of a program that reads in particle structure objects and prints the details of each particle. I understand how the **C** program works but am confused about the "filea" binary file that contains the "structure objects". How is the data being automatically assigned to the values of the structs in the **C** program? The filea, being binary, isn't comprehensible so I'm not sure exactly how it is working and when I asked him about it I didn't get a clear answer.

Here is the program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vector{
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
};

struct particle {
        float mass;
        struct vector pos;
        struct vector vel;
};

int main(int argc, int *argv[]) {
    int cnt = 0;
    int fd, nbytes;
    struct particle *buf = (struct particle *)malloc(sizeof(struct particle)); 
    fd = open("filea",O_RDONLY); 

    while ((nbytes = read(fd,buf,sizeof(struct particle))) > 0){
        printf("Particle %d\n", cnt++);
        printf("\tmass\t%.1f\n",buf->mass);
        printf("\tpos\t(%.1f,%.1f,%.1f)\n",buf->pos.x,buf->pos.y,buf->pos.z);
        printf("\tvel\t(%.1f,%.1f,%.1f)\n",buf->vel.x,buf->vel.y,buf->vel.z);
    }   
    close(fd);
    free(buf);

    return 1;
}
```

The slide said "Each particle is represented by the structures:"

```
struct vector {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct particle {
    float mass;
    struct vector pos;
    struct vector vel;
};
```

Comment: Consider using the functions of the `fopen()` / `fread()` family instead. They support buffering, which causes the repetition of read/write operations to be much faster. Reading a file with `read()` will access the HD every time, this can be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two structures, `vector` and `particle` are fixed length structures. `vector` is 3 floats, so if we assume a 4 byte float, that structure is 12 bytes, and `particle` is made up of 1 float and 3 vectors, so 4 bytes + 3 * 12, for a total of 40 bytes.

`read` takes the pointer to the file stream, a memory address (in this case a buffer the size of a `particle`), and a size (again, the size of a `particle`). It returns the number of bytes read (I think, it may return the number of blocks of data read).

So, read literally transfers the bytes from the file in to the buffer pointed at by `buf`. `buf` happens to be typed as a pointer to `particle`, so all of the structure operators conveniently work (as seen by the `printf` statements).

When the `read` reaches the end of file, it will "fail" and return a 0 instead of the count of the data read, and that terminates the loop.

The data on the disk must match the internal, binary layout of the structures and the floats within those structures, otherwise you will get garbage data. For example, if you wrote the file on a machine that is "little endian" and read the file on a "big endian" machine, it's very likely the data would be corrupted, since the internal representations likely differ due to the endianess,

This technique is an efficient, and simple, mechanism for store and reading data, but is not portable.

Comment: It was incredibly difficult choosing a best answer but this one answered some small details I didn't understand that I couldn't quite figure how to write in a question formally. I learned a lot from every answer so thnx everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It works by reading the variables in exactly the same order as they have been declared.
The `particle` struct starts with a variable called `mass` of type `float`, so the first thing that is read is a total of 4 bytes (assuming that a `float` is 4 bytes) and that is assigned to `mass`. Then comes a `struct vector` called `pos`, and it contains three floats, so these are read next in that same order. That is, the next 4 bytes are assigned to `pos.x`, then the next 4 bytes are assigned to `pos.y`, and the next 4 to `pos.z`. The same thing is repeated for `vel`.

This is all done in one sigle step: an entire block with the size of the struct `particle` is read and copied to `buf`, and everything is expected to get copied to its correct location. This works if the declaration of `struct particle` has not changed, otherwise it would not. This technique is fast, but depends heavily on a fixed declaration of the struct. And, because it is using a binary file, it also is machine-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

This call:

```
read(fd,buf,sizeof(struct particle))
```

...fills the contents pointed to by `buf` with the data from the file.  `buf` is aliased to a `struct particle`, so you should expect `filea`'s contents to be a series of seven single-precision floating point values (one value for `mass`, one ordinate triple for `pos` followed by one ordinate triple for `vel`).  The sequence of the values in `struct particle` is the expected sequence of values in the contents of `filea`.

Note that this practice is sometimes frowned upon because of problems with portability.  Endianness (not at issue with this example) and alignment/padding are opportunities for portability issues when using a `struct`'s in-memory representation as its serialized-to-disk (or network) representation.  A way to mitigate this is to define a file format which is independent of the in-memory representation.  The unfortunate cost is that you must often write each field independently.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare structs in C, the memory is laid out in a very specific fashion. The variables are right next to each other in memory. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882420/structure-memory-layout-in-c) has a decent illustration.

Your professor wrote a c program to write that out to that file. One can then read the file because you know the size of the struct (and since the variables were next to each other in memory) you can recover the entire data structure.

This line reads `sizeof(struct particle)` bytes into fd, and places them into buf.

```
read(fd,buf,sizeof(struct particle))
```

Thus loading the struct that (presumably) your professor wrote to the file.

Because of difference in platform implementation of primitive types in c, this binary file may not be portable to other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor saved the particle data to the file as bytes. Since the size of `struct particle` is fixed, the example code can then `read` the file in chunks with the size `sizeof(struct particle)` that match the structure of `struct particle`.

This approach is convenient for an example like this, but there are too many assumptions on the machine's memory model for it to be a portable solution.